# Matplotlib subplot2grid plotting IndexError in pandas 0.16.1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have (5) pandas series i'm trying to plot on (5) graphs. i want to have them so that they look like this format with the 5th chart on the last row by itself, centered (don't focus on the contents of the charts, just the positioning)
[image]

But in pandas 0.16.1, I get an Index Error on the 5th chart. Here's a MCVE example of my issue that you guys can copy and paste and try for yourself.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure() 

firstperiod = pd.Series({1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:3, 5:4}) 
secondperiod = pd.Series({1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:2}) 
thirdperiod = pd.Series({1:4, 2:4, 3:5, 4:1, 5:1, 6:3}) 
fourthperiod = pd.Series({1:3, 2:3, 3:1, 4:6, 5:7, 6:5})
fifthperiod = pd.Series({1:2, 2:2, 3:1, 4:5, 5:5})

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,0], 2, 2) 
firstperiod.plot(kind='hist', bins=5) 

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,2], 2, 2) 
secondperiod.plot(kind='hist', bins=4) 

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [2,1], 2, 2) 
thirdperiod.plot(kind="hist", bins=6) 

ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [2,2], 2, 2) 
fourthperiod.plot(kind="hist", bins=6) 

ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [4,1], 2, 2) 
fifthperiod.plot(kind="hist", bins=5) 

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

It executes until the last (5th) chart and then this pops up:

`IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4`

What gives? and how to fix this?

thanks in advance guys,appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are after... I have added `plt.ion()` to bring it into interactive mode and `plt.draw()` to add each figure as you define it.

By doing this it becomes obvious that the axis is defined as `(y,x)` not `(x,y)`...

[This reference](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/gridspec.html) might also help in the future

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()

firstperiod = pd.Series({1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:3, 5:4}) 
secondperiod = pd.Series({1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:2}) 
thirdperiod = pd.Series({1:4, 2:4, 3:5, 4:1, 5:1, 6:3}) 
fourthperiod = pd.Series({1:3, 2:3, 3:1, 4:6, 5:7, 6:5})
fifthperiod = pd.Series({1:2, 2:2, 3:1, 4:5, 5:5})

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,4), (0,0), colspan=2) 
firstperiod.plot(kind='hist', bins=5) 
plt.draw()
raw_input()

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,4), (0,2), colspan=2) 
secondperiod.plot(kind='hist', bins=4) 
plt.draw()
raw_input()

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,4), (1,0), colspan=2) 
thirdperiod.plot(kind="hist", bins=6) 
plt.draw()
raw_input()

ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,4), (1,2), colspan=2)
fourthperiod.plot(kind="hist", bins=6) 
plt.draw()
raw_input()

ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3,4), (2,1), colspan=2)
fifthperiod.plot(kind="hist", bins=5)
plt.draw()
raw_input()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
```

I changed the column height from 6 to 3 because the graph you showed above had the `colspan` as twice the `rowspan`

Comment: does this work for you? this doesn't plot anything for me - and the `plt.tight_layout` line gives me an error like this: 

`ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: the closest i got your version to work was taking out the `plt.tight_layout` and then having to add `plt.ioff()` and
`plt.show()` at the end of the code. Can you double check yours and advise otherwise? I've also found that in this case, i get the same result without `plt.draw()` and `raw_input()` - @alexmcf

Comment: Ok I had moved the `plt.tight_layout()` to to top just before I posted my answer - didn't realise it would mess the plot up! check out my edited version where I do `plt.tight_layout()` at the end instead... For your final version, remove all the `plt.draw()`, `raw_input()`, `plt.ion()` and append a `plt.show()` at the end. The latter is just to confirm for you that the plot is working correctly...

Comment: it did. sorry i was away for the weekend. thanks again!